# i had 2 arrays with objects and the same nameobject should be cancelled only one time

Tags: iphone, ios

I have input as two arrays shown below

```
NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"1", nil];
```

the output should resemble like this.
the same element should be cancelled only one time.

```
NSArray *array3=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.....

Comment: compare both arrays and save those elements that do not match.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, edit your question with a better explanation.

Comment: hi atxe,the same example can be seen in flames game while cancelling the same letters and the remaining letters should be printed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSCountedSet` for the above situation

```
 NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"r",@"a",@"r",@"r",@"r", nil]; 

    NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"b",@"c",@"r", nil];


    NSMutableSet *setOne = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: array1];
    NSSet *setTwo = [NSSet setWithArray: array2];

    [setOne unionSet:setTwo];

    NSArray *arrayOneResult = [setOne allObjects];

    NSLog(@"%@",arrayOneResult);

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:arrayOneResult];

    for (id item in set)
    {

        NSCountedSet *set1 = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array1];
        NSCountedSet *set2 = [[NSCountedSet alloc]initWithArray:array2];

        int diff = abs([set1 countForObject:item] - [set2 countForObject:item]);

        for (int  i = 0 ;i < diff ;i++ ) {
            [resultArray addObject:item];
        }


    }

    NSLog(@"the array : %@",resultArray   );
```

Comment: @Ramgopal:Welcome...please upvote and/or tick the answer if appropriate so that it can be of great help for users in the near future

Comment: NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"4",@"4", nil];
    
    NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"1",@"4", nil];
    
    try by taking the above arrays--->
    
    the o/p should be 3,4,4,1.

Comment: not still...check for the below arrays..  NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"4", nil];
    
    NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"1", nil];
    
    the o/p i need is 3,4,4,1.

Comment: is it that the number appearing in multiples of 2 should appear twice only ?

Comment: ok..string in your case,but still should an object appearing in multiples of 2 say 4 or 8 times should appear twice only in the output array??

Comment: no...NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"r",@"a",@"r",@"r",@"r", nil]; NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"b",@"c",@"r", nil];.the o/p should be a,r,r,r,b,c

Comment: my output is same as the flames game(cancelling the letters)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

NSArray *array2 = @[@"1",@"2",@"1"];

NSMutableSet *allElemets = [NSSet setWithArray:array1];
[allElemets addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

This will return you all elements without duplicates.
In this case it will be

> @"1",@"2",@"3"

Edit:

This will return the intersection of the arrays

```
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];
[set1 intersectSet:set2];
```

Answer (score 0):

f you are fine with sets instead of arrays, you can use NSMutableSet instead of NSArray. NSMutableSet has nice methods like intersectSet: and minusSet:

Comment: but set is not taking up the duplicate value(same objects) @rushi

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[array1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]])
{

            [array2 removeObjectAtIndex: i];                
            NSLog(@"same element removed.");

}

array3 = [firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

or

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array2];

array3 = [set allObjects];
```

Two arrays are compared and duplicate values are removed, you get your values.

Comment: i am getting wrong output .the output through our code will be 1,2,3 objects in array.@randeep

Answer (score 0):

**Here tHe Code goes**

**EDIt: This WOuld remove the Duplicate Value add Unique value.**

```
NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"1", nil];

//Here Create nEw  Array with Arra1 
NSMutableArray * newArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array1];
for(int index=0; index<[array2 count];index++)
{
    id object =[array2 objectAtIndex:index];
    if(![newArray containsObject:object])//this methods Returns YES/NO 
    {
        [newArray addObject: object];

    }

}
```